# Packaging resources with setuptools/distribute

Tags: python, setuptools, distribute, pypi

I'm developing an Python egg that has several .txt dependencies (they're templates used to generate files by the egg itself), and I'm struggling to get those dependencies copied to `site-packages` during `setup.py install`. According to the [`distribute` documentation](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#automatic-resource-extraction)...

**Filesystem of my package:**

```
setup.py
package
|--- __init__.py
|--- main.py
|--- binary (calls main.py with pkg_resources.load_entry_point)
|--- templates
     |--file1.txt
     |--file2.txt
```

**In setup.py:**

```
setup(
    [...]
    eager_resources = ['templates/file1.txt', 'templates/file2.txt']
)
```

**Within my package:**

```
from pkg_resources import resource_string
tpl = resource_string(__name__, 'templates/file1.txt')
```

...this combination of configuration and filesystem should result in `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` being available through `pkg_resources.resource_string`. Unfortunately, they're not being copied to `site-packages` during `setup.py install`. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information can be found in the setuptools documentation for including package data: [https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#including-data-files)

Basically, you just need to set `include_package_data=True` in your setup.py file.  If you are using subversion or CVS, all versioned files will be included.  If not, you can specify which files to include with a MANIFEST.in file.

I believe distribute supports this as well.

You can then access the files as you would without them being packaged. i.e. in main.py you could have:

```
import os.path
f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates','file1.txt'))
print f.read()
f.close()
```

and this would work in the packaged version as well.  One caveat is that you will have to also set `zip_safe = False` in setup.py so that all the files are unzipped during installation.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the help. Would you mind clarifying the difference between "data files" and "resources", as defined by the setuptools documentation you linked to? I was following the instructions for resources, but they appear to be qualitatively different. Thanks!

Comment: Well, your question was the first time I've ever come across "resources" so I too am curious what they are for.  But data files are definitely the way to go for stuff like templates.

Comment: Note that you need not use zip_safe=False. Instead, use pkg_resources.resource_stream('packagename', 'templates/file1.txt').read() and setuptools will get the stream for you from the filesystem or from the zipped egg.

Comment: The documentation specifically recommends against using `__file__` type access for packaged data (http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#accessing-data-files-at-runtime). Use the [Resource Management API](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs#resource-management) like the OP was already using, and like @JasonR.Coombs suggested.

Comment: This solution only works when using a manifest file or a version control system. Is there a way to do this using only the `package_data` (or `eager_resources`) arguments of `setup`?